# Send request depending on a condition from a previous request

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch

I want to send request depending on a condition from a previous request.

This is my code:

```
const sendFriendRequest_ver_2 = (requestFrom, requestTo, requestFromUserType = "INDIVIDUAL_USER", requestToUserType = "INDIVIDUAL_USER") => {

const data = {
    requestFrom,
    requestTo,
    requestFromUserType,
    requestToUserType,
}
api.get(`/api/friendship-request?userId=${requestTo}&userType=INDIVIDUAL_USER`)
    .then(res => {
        const found = res.data.some(item => item.id === requestFrom);
        if (found) {
            console.log('invite already sent')
        } else {
            console.log('sending now')
            api.post('/api/friendship-request', data).then(res => {
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))

        }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

It works but I am new to programing and I am not sure if this is the 'best' way to do this.

I mean I dont't know if this is good way to handle this at all.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have written makes sense and you don't need to worry much about it. If you are familiar with async await syntax you should change it to that. its just more readable. Here is a layout:

```
const sendFriendRequest_ver_2 = (requestFrom, requestTo, requestFromUserType = "INDIVIDUAL_USER", requestToUserType = "INDIVIDUAL_USER") => {

const data = {
requestFrom,
requestTo,
requestFromUserType,
requestToUserType,
}
(async()=>{
try{
  const res = await api.get(`/api/friendship-request?userId=${requestTo}userType=INDIVIDUAL_USER`)
  const found = res.data.some(item => item.id === requestFrom);
  if (found) {
        console.log('invite already sent')
    } else {
        console.log('sending now')
      const res =  await api.post('/api/friendship-request', data)

    }
 }
 catch(error){
      console.log(e)
 }
 })()
```

Comment: You removed error handling from the 2nd request.  An error there would not be logged or caught.

Comment: It's in the try block if it will throw some error both will be matched by the last catch block.

Comment: No, that's not the case.  In `const res =  api.post('/api/friendship-request', data)`, there is no `await` so an error there will NOT go to the `try/catch` block.

Comment: Oh yeah I missed that await thanks for pointing.